# How to copy formatted text into Word 2010 without it being put into a table?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, text-formatting

When I copy text that contains bullets into Word, Word puts it into a table, which restricts justification and integrating with regular text. When trying to select or move text, one keeps snagging the border which increases indentation of everything.  When I copy formatted text, I want to retain the formatting, but still be able to edit each line and paragraph individually.  I usually have merge formatting set so that the font becomes my local font choice.  But how do I do it without it being stuck in a table?

Answer (score 1):

If the text is inserted to Word with a table that means that the source of text data was put into table (it may be invisible if HTML border = 0). In order not to copy text with table but keeping the source formatting, you need to make sure that when selecting text to copy in doesn't include a space indent that actually copies a text with a table cell. I.e. you need to make sure that you don't copy the whole paragraph but only the text inside it.
To do this, I usually copy text without the leading and ending symbol to make sure that cell formatting is not copied together with the text.